# How to build News Tagging model(s)

Tags: topic-model

I am trying to build a news tagging system. Given a piece of news article, find 5-6 key terms from the news article that best describe the article. Refer to the image below from google news.

[image]

What are some approaches I can look at to get human readable tags ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the tags for the headline or news content using NLP. Tags are generally noun chunks, entities or the action mentioned in the headline. You need to perform standard steps of text processing i.e remove stop words, tokenize sentence into words, do stemming or lemmatization then parse it to extract information. Most of these are already implemented. Look into [spaCy](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features) or use [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/).

You can also look into [SVO](https://medium.com/@acrosson/extract-subject-matter-of-documents-using-nlp-e284c1c61824) (Subject, verb, object model) to assign tags. SpaCy provides an easy way to do this, do check it out.